# Blank String Default Value in Entity Framework Designer

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to assign a blank string (i.e. "") as a Default Value in the Entity Framework's EDMX designer? The only technique I've found is to edit the edmx file manually using a text editor

Answer (score 14):

I realize that this is an extremely old question, but for posterity's sake, in the EF4 designer you can type a space in the properties window field, then hit backspace, leaving the field empty instead of the default value of (None).  For strings, this seems to default to String.Empty.

Answer (score 4):

What I did was to create a default constructor in a partial class where I set

```
_privateFieldName = string.Empty;
```

The partial class obviously would be in a different file and won't get regenerated by the designer.  The only downside to this method is that now any changes to the default value  in the designer will not apply

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the only way that I've found to set an empty string as the default value is to edit the EDMX.  Editing the designer file doesn't work as the code is regenerated.

This is really a bug in the entity framework that needs to be addressed.

EDIT:  Actually, setting an empty string in XML is quite painful so it might be easier to just set the value to string.Empty in the application when creating a new entity.